# Output of sentence convolution neural network yielding dimension equals to word embedding

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

From [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2188.pdf) article titled **A Convolutional Neural Network for Modelling Sentences**, it is mentioned in section 2.2 that generation the output of a convolution layer is determined by the formula of:

[image]

where `m` refers to the size of the weight matrix with dimension `d x m` , `s` refers to the sentence matrix of dimension `d x s` , `d` refers to the size of word embedding, and `j` refers to an index.

Mathematically based on the formula above, `Cj` should have the dimension of `m x( (m-1) x s)`. 
It is also mentioned that the dimension of `c` for wide convolution is `d x (s+m-1)`.  I understand that using wide convolution method will generate an index of `j` from `1` to `(s+m-1)` and hence explains the `s+m-1` part of output layer dimension `d x (s+m-1)` of the convolutional layer, but my question is why does it have the preserve the size of `d` for each index of convolutional output layer (i.e. why isn't the dimension `m x( (m-1) x s)` instead of `d`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer, but please correct me if I'm wrong : 
Turns out the convolution is using a one-dimensional convolution, meaning only 1 particular dimension size is changed (that is `s`) but not the other dimensions (such as `d`).

Therefore, dimension `d` is still preserved, and it is correct that `Cj` will have the dimension `m x((m-1) x s)` and `c` ,to be precise,  will have the dimension of 
`d x (s+m-1) x dim(Cj)` OR 
`d x (s+m-1) x (m x ((m-1) x s))`